# Possibilities of summing up 10 numbers subject to some restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

How do I find the number of possible ways to sum up 10 numbers for the following problem?

$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_{10} = 27$, where $, 1 \leq x_i \leq 4$ for $x_i$ where $i=1,2,3,...,10$

I tried to apply the constraint $x_i \leq 4$ but that gives me a negative integer on the right hand side. The normal combinatoric equation $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ doesn't seem helpful if right hand side is smaller than zero.

Comment: I don't see why you should get a negative integer on the RHS.

Comment: @trueblueanil Clearly we cannot have all 10 integers being 4, otherwise the sum will be 40 which is greater than 27. But then how do we choose the integer solutions with the restrictions on $x_i$ being fulfilled?

Comment: The constraint is $x_i \le4$, not $x_i =4$ . Try stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are interested in the stars and bars solution.

Firstly, solve for $x'_1 +x'_2 +...x'_{10} = 17$ without the upper constraint, and then exclude "bad" solutions by deliberately putting $4$ in one or more $x'i$ to get $$\binom{26}9 - \binom{10}1\binom{22}9+\binom{10}2\binom{18}9 - .... = 100,110 $$

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). In your problem, the # of solutions is just the coefficient of the term $x^{27}$ in the polynomial
$$
(x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)^{10} = x^{10}(1+x)^{10}(1+x^2)^{10}
$$
which is relatively easy to compute.

---

Another method is by recursion. Denote the # of solutions of
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = m
$$
as $f(m, n)$. We have in your problem that
$$
f(m, n) = f(m - 1, n-1) + f(m - 2, n - 1) + f(m - 3, n - 1) + f(m - 4, n - 1)
$$
which can be computed easily by dynamic programming using computers.

Comment: You might also consider the identity $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{10} = x^{10} (1-x^4)^{10} (1-x)^{-10}$

Answer (score 0):

The above solution seems complicated. I wish to use some basic combinatorics (perhaps along with inclusion-exclusion) to solve it. Now I try to impose the restriction $x \geq 1$ first. To do this, the equation becomes $x'_1+x'_2+x'_3+...+x'_{10} = 17$

But I really have no idea what I should do next.

(Sorry if I shouldn't response to my own question like this, I'm new to the community...)